# How to get the file relative path in c# service project?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
Stream stream = new StreamReader("~/quartz.xml").BaseStream;
```

Q1:What is the "~" symbol specify path in C#?

Q2:How to get the "~" directory in C# service project?

Q3:Does it mean the bin exe directory or project name directory?

The `quartz.xml` file in my Windows service project located in two position:

```
D:\jsptpd\Code\jsptpdJobScheduler\jsptpdJobScheduler\bin\Debug

D:\jsptpd\Code\jsptpdJobScheduler\jsptpdJobScheduler
```

Sure the path will change everytime!So get the relative path is better.

Comment: The `~` is only defined in the context of **ASP.NET** - it's not a general C# concept and therefore isn't available in a .NET Service.

Answer (score 3):

Just omit it entirely:

```
Stream stream = new StreamReader("quartz.xml").BaseStream;
```

The default directory *is* the `.exe`'s directory.

---

Per the OP's edit to the question:

Go to *View* > *Solution Explorer*. Right-click the file in question, then choose *Properties*. Change the *Copy To Output Directory* option to *Copy Always*. Then use the code above.

Comment: How to find where my quartz.xml if not specify the directory?

Comment: The quartz.xml is not in the exe dirctory!

Comment: @Dolphin Then where is it? O.o

Comment: If not specify the path,does the StreamReader can find the file right way?

Comment: @Dolphin: if the `quartz.xml` is not in the `.exe` directory, then you **must** specify the directory somehow - explicitly, in a config file, absolute or relative to the `.exe` directory - but you **have to define** where to find that file!

Comment: If you don't specify the path, it goes to the `.exe`'s directory, like I said. **edit:** Marc's comment hits the nail on the head.

Comment: so now i want to give the relative path of the xml file!But how?

Comment: @Dolphin How hard can it be? I fail to understand where you're going wrong here... you could use, e.g. `@"../quartz.xml"` or `@"C:/quartz.xml"`

Comment: I just want to give the accurate relative path of the xml file,so make sure the StreamReader can find it correct,oh  i know,thank you!'

Comment: @Dolphin: then **PLEASE TELL US** where that file is! Assuming you're in the `.exe` directory - **WHERE IS THE FILE?!?!?!?!**

Comment: Thank you Marc, I don't think I would've been quite so polite :p

Comment: Go to *View* > *Solution Explorer*. Right-click the file in question, then choose *Properties*. Change the *Copy To Output Directory* option to *Copy Always*. Then use the code in my answer.

Comment: OK,thank you very much,if you have patient to look my old question,you would know how i afraid to set the Copy To Output Directory option to Copy Always

Comment: Just so you know what's happening here, in that case, every time you compile/run your code, the file will be copied from your project's folder to the .exe's folder.

Comment: @marc_s What do you make of the answer the OP has posted? I'm even more confused now...

Answer (score 1):

if we use(../quartz.xml):

the StreamReader read path is(not the file actual path):

```
C:\Windows\quartz.xml
```

if we use(quartz.xml):

the StreamReader read path is(not the file actual path):

```
C:\Windows\system32\quartz.xml
```

This is the way to find the file relative path:

```
                string assemblyFilePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
                string assemblyDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyFilePath);
                string configFilePath = assemblyDirPath + "\\quartz.xml";
                Stream stream = new StreamReader(configFilePath).BaseStream;
```

So the path is(you can specify either of two):

```
D:\jsptpd\Code\jsptpdJobScheduler\jsptpdJobScheduler\bin\Debug\quartz.xml
```